# when training object detection classifier --> ImportError: No module named tensorflow

Tags: python, windows, object-detection

after using the below command

```
python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images/train_labels.csv --image_dir=images/train --output_path=train.record
```

I received the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 16, in
import tensorflow as tf
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

How to overcome this error?

Comment: You are missing the library tensorflow. Please follow the instructions here to install. https://www.tensorflow.org/install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `pip freeze` if you don't find tensorflow  in list then install using below command.

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Comment: thank you, Sanjay. but I got another error as "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."